# Embedding Google map inside div tags inside more div tags

Tags: google-maps, html

I'm having problems embedding a Google map inside multiple div tags inside a webpage.

If I declare the map div () outside the div tags(i.e. in the body only) it works. But it is either right at the top or bottom of my page. If I declare it inside the div where I want it, it doesn't show. Almost as though it is underneath the tag contents.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I solved the problem.

The original declaration - div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%" - doesn't work Because of the style format of the previous div tags it returns the height as 0 and 100% of 0 is still 0. So Explicitly setting the height attribute to 100px works.

Solution: div id="map_canvas" style="width:100px; height:100px"

Happy Holidays Everyone! Luben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The original declaration - div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%" - doesn't work
Because of the style css format of the previous div tags it returns the height as 0 and 100% of 0 is still 0. So Explicitly setting the height attribute to 100px works.

Solution:
div id="map_canvas" style="width:100px; height:100px"

Happy